# Multiple tests with minitest

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, tdd, bdd, minitest

I have an app with some specs written into [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest). As usual, I start them using `rake`.

Because some times I got a random results, my specs can pass one time, and fail an other time.

In this case, I can keep the sequence number and replay it later, after fixing.
Because I have this kind of tests (with a random result), I generally run `rake` many time, just to be sure that the app is okay.

I would like to know if there is a nice way to perform multiple `rake` tests (100 times for example), and stop them if there any failure or any error?

Comment: A not-so-nice version: Build a  new task to call rake via backticks and analyse the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dummy test with random result to simulate your situation:

```
#store it as file 'testcase.rb'
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'

class X < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_1
    num = rand(10) 
    assert_true( num < 5, "Value is #{num}")
  end
end
```

The following task calls the test 10 times and stops after the first failure:

```
TEST_REPETION = 10
task :test do
  TEST_REPETION.times{
    stdout = `ruby testcase.rb`

    if stdout =~ /\d+\) Failure/
      puts "Failure occured"
      puts stdout
      exit
    else
      puts 'Tests ok'
    end
  }
end
```

For real usage I would adapt some parts:

- Instead `puts 'Tests ok'` define a counter to see how often the test was succussfull
- Instead `puts stdout`you may store the result in a result file?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should think again about your test, not about the test call. A test with a  random result looks wrong for me.

What's the random factor in your test? Can you write a mock-element for the random factor and repeat the test with different values for the mock-element. So you get a "complete" test.

Comment: I agree.  But for now, I'll just wanna run the `rake` command some times.  And in the future, I will rewrite all this sh***. :)