# Re-run failed unit tests in ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I have some unit tests written using Test::Unit::TestCase, with XML generated by ci_reporter. However, due to circumstances beyond my control, they may occasionally fluctuate, and randomly fail. I'd like to detect when a test fails, and attempt to re-run it.

I tried doing this by monkey-patching 'teardown' to check 'passed?', and re-running the tests on a failure. However, the XML output will still show the first failed case, and not the second (now passing) run.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435584/multiple-tests-with-minitest/7436257#7436257

Comment: Thanks for the response @knut, but alas this is something beyond my control, and un-mockable. There's a random factor, and I have to live with it, and find a way to work around it.

Comment: Ooops, I linked to an answer. I wanted to link the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435584/multiple-tests-with-minitest/ -- I will make an answer.

Comment: There's always exceptions, but random factors are generally able to be handled using pseudo-randomness such as introducing a constant random seed so the results are always the same. If you don't have that, it's hard to reliably automate testing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like the opposite of [Multiple tests with minitest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435584/multiple-tests-with-minitest/)

Perhaps this is a possibility: Copy your test case in an own file. As an example, try the following test:

```
#store it as file 'testcase.rb'
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'

class X < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_1
    num = rand(10) 
    assert_true( num < 2, "Value is #{num}")
  end
end
```

Then define your test call in a rake task:

```
require 'rake'

TEST_REPETION = 10
task :test do
  success = false
  TEST_REPETION.times{
    stdout = `ruby testcase.rb`

    if stdout =~ /Failure/
      puts "Failure occured - redo the test"
    else
      puts 'Tests ok'
      success = true
      exit 
    end
  }

  puts "Stopped after #{TEST_REPETION} tries" unless success
end
```

Now the test is called, until the test succeed or `TEST_REPETION` are done.

Remarks:

- Rake isn't needed, you may do the call without rake ([My template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7447388/676874) was a rake task)
- This works only, if your xml changes for each run (it must be regenerated before the test. else you test always the same).
- You may store the test result (`stdout`) in a file and use it later to analyze, which tests failed and try to retest them.